# Doxygen escape nested comments in C

Tags: c, doxygen

Im writing a docstring in doxygen within a C comment block, and I want to include a snippet that contains `/* text */`

I know I could include a file, but this is just 8 characters or so. and it needs to be `/* text */`, not `// text` (since Im documenting the behavior of a C source code parser).

Is there some way to escape the characters so something like this is possible without causing problems for Doxygen or the compiler?

```
/**
 * This is a doxy comment.
 *
 * This parser supports C style formatted comments: ``/* text */``
 */
```

*Realize I could use C++ comments here for the main doxygen comment block. but still curious if this is possible without doing that (would mean changing a large comment block for this one snippet alone).*

Comment: In version 1.8.7. &zwj; exists (see chapter 24 HTML commands of the documentation). Did you try (it is a bit of a trick): This parser C supports style formatted comments: ``/&zwj;* text *&zwj;/``

Comment: @albert, Great! that works, could you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 1.8.7. `&zwj;` exists (see chapter 24 HTML commands of the documentation). Did you try (it is a bit of a trick):
`This parser C supports style formatted comments: /&zwj;* text *&zwj;/`

Comment: Maybe less tricky if you use `&lowast;` to write `*`.
Try it like: `/&lowast; text &lowast;/`
This way no more output are added by doxygen on HTML

Answer (score 1):

Nesting comments is not possible...

> **C99** *6.9.4 Comments*
>
> 1 Except within a character constant, a string literal, or a comment, the characters /*
>   introduce a comment. The contents of such a comment are examined only to identify
>   multibyte characters and to find the characters */ that terminate it.<sup>70)</sup>
>
> <sup>70)</sup> Thus, /* ... */ comments do not nest.

You have to do something like this:

```
/**
 * This is a doxy comment.
 *
 * This parser supports C style formatted comments: /* text *//*
 */
```

Notice the difference:

```
/* text *//*
```

Comment: Realize on the C side it can't be done, but doxygen may have some way to substitute a `*` character.

Answer (score 1):

I recently have been attempting the same thing for the purposes of a `\code` block LaTeX output.

Simply leave a space between the trailing `*` and `/`. This does show as a space in the resultant PDF, but using it without the space appears exactly the same. The result is still correctly syntax-colored in the PDF but also allows your source to retain the correct syntax coloring and stops your source compiler throwing errors:

```
/**
  \code{.c}
      /* ... * /
  \endocde
 */
```

Comment: Edited to add the `{.c}`. This may or may not be pertinent to the syntax displaying correctly in this case, but I had used it in my real code where this method is working.